# Is the [DataMember] attribute needed on virtual properties?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4

Is the [DataMember] attribute needed on virtual properties?

```
[DataMember]
public string Title { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

or is this the correct way:

```
[DataMember]
public string Title { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Comment: So it's needed only if i need to access the virtual property on the wcf client?

Comment: It has nothing to do with virtual or not. The question is: do you want `User` to be serialized or not? Yes if you want to access it in the client.

Comment: Thank you. That's all i needed to know. You create an answer if you want, so that i can accept it as my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to the property being virtual or not. If you want a property to be serialized (i.e. visible for a WCF client) you mark it as `DataMember`.

Keep in mind that if you do that, `ApplicationUser` should also be a `DataContract`, otherwise you get an exception like

> Type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. ...